# Is it possible to always work in a virtual machine / create full machine backups (not tied to particular hardware?)

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, backup, virtualization

I've recently had a hardware failure with my personal machine and need to temporarily use a different computer while waiting for parts etc. Setting this up for me to work (often coding) productively & restoring backed up data took a bit of time (even with automated install routines like boxstarter / chocolatey) which is annoying.

This got me thinking: **is it possible to create a full environment backup that can be ported between different machines?** System image backups wouldn't work I don't think since the hardware may be different.

Would there be merits in working full-time in a virtual machine? This would be easy enough to move between machines I'd guess and could even be run temporarily from an external hard-drive, meaning the only requirement on the "guest" machine would be e.g. installing VirtualBox.

However, I'd guess this would give an undesirable performance hit (a bad thing when running numerical simulations in my day job) and the need to maintain both the OS running Virtual Box on my main computer, plus the virtual OS in which I work?

I hope this isn't seen as off-topic, but I'd be interested to hear of any thoughts / suggestions towards creating a productive work environment, ideally portable.

Comment: if you really want to go mobile and not tied to any specific hardware, you can use Amazon Workspace, see https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/ . You only need Internet connection to access your virtual desktop

Answer (score 1):

I've tried doing this myself using VirtualBox and moving the image around but it grows in size and after a while moving it around becomes a chore on it's own.

One option you might want to consider is having backups of you work sync to the cloud and using provisioning to configure the environment. Something like https://github.com/naggie/dotfiles would let you set up every pc the same each time.

You could also use something like Ansible, just showing this repo as I've used it before.